# Need to remove focus from edit text when user hides soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I have an issue with my app where the user cannot click back into a text box after minimising the soft keyboard. Users often miss spell search words and are unable to click back into a edit text box to bring up a soft keyboard as it already has focus (applications gives them the highlight cursor instead).

Is there any way to catch the keyboard hide event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to  catch the keyboard hide event

```
  @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int actualHeight = getHeight();

        if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
            // Keyboard is shown
        } else {
            // Keyboard is hidden
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

Also you can call `requestFocus()` on some other view to remove focus from your EditText.

Comment: this doesnt really fit in with how my layouts are made, at the moment the root is justa linear layout in the xml